# How do I do a simple regression multiple times?

Tags: r, lm

I've seen a few variations of this question, but they don't seem to specifically answer what I'm trying to accomplish. I have a data frame (`df`):

```
month  ter     dist     emp_count  var1     var2
1      1       10       21         3000     5120
2      1       10       20         3100     5340
3      1       10       20         3100     5543
4      1       10       21         3250     5625
5      1       10       24         3200     5254
6      1       10       25         3300     5634
7      1       10       26         3600     5435
8      1       10       26         3900     7546
.      .       .        .          .        .
.      .       .        .          .        .
.      .       .        .          .        .
```

`ter` holds the values 1, 2, 3, or 4. And `dist` can be any number 1 thru 50. I want to do a simple regression multiple times based on `ter` or `dist`

I have this:

```
model = lm(var1 ~ emp_count, data = df)
summary(model)
```

But I'd rather not write out a regression 50 times if I want to compare based on `dist`.

Answer (score 3):

Split by your iter or dist, then lapply your fit and summary

```
lapply(split(df, df$dist), function(x) summary(lm(var1 ~ emp_count, data = x)))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only need the coefficients and p-values, then you can use lmList from nlme or lme4:

```
library(lme4)

df = data.frame(dist=rep(1:50,each=50),
month=sample(1:12,2500,replace=TRUE),
emp_count=rpois(20,2500),
var1=rpois(2500,40),var2=rpois(2500,50))

lmList(var1 ~ emp_count | dist,data=df)

Call: lmList(formula = var1 ~ emp_count | dist, data = df) 
Coefficients:
   (Intercept)     emp_count
1    9.9885028  1.257080e-02
2   96.5774029 -2.238488e-02
3   11.5427710  1.143071e-02
4   37.5422288  8.699393e-04
5  -44.4468575  3.367506e-02
6   50.4651290 -4.084562e-03
```

To get p-values,std error etc:

```
summary(lmList(var1 ~ emp_count | dist,data=df))
```

Answer (score 1):

Other solution can be accomplished using `dplyr` and `broom` packages. Here is the code for your example. First you need to extract the coefficients and p values for the intercept and slope for every linear model (lm), grouped by the variable dist. `tidy` is like the `summary` function used for `summary(lm)`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(broom)

lmodelsCoef <- df %>%
  group_by(dist) %>% 
  do(tidy(lm(ar1 ~ emp_count, .)))

lmodelsCoef <- lmodelsCoef %>% 
  group_by(dist) %>%
  summarize(intercept = estimate[1],
            p.value_intercept = p.value[1],
            slope = estimate[2],
            p.value_slope = p.value[2])
```

Next you need to extract the r squared value. However, this value is found in the `lm` object (not in the `summary(lm)` one). Therefore, you need to use `glance` for that.

```
lmodelsCoef2 <- df %>%
  group_by(dist) %>% 
  do(glance(lm(ar1 ~ emp_count, .)))

lmodelsCoef2 <- lmodelsCoef2 %>% 
  group_by(dist) %>%
  summarize(r.squared = r.squared)

#Get the final df
df_lm<-data.frame(lmodelsCoef,
                    r.squared = lmodelsCoef2$r.squared)
```